# Wordpress redirect from posts index.html

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am working on wordpress project. Url to my category link is

http://mywebsite.com/cardfinder/hotel_credit_cards/index.html .

I want it should be redirected to

http://mywebsite.com/cardfinder/hotel_credit_cards

Is there any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `.htaccess` rule in root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have already tried it. It redirects me to http://mywebsite.com/hotel_credit_cards while I want it to http://mywebsite.com/cardfinder/hotel_credit_cards. Cardfinder is my base directory for this I am keeping .htacess to cardfinder folder.